# Sendmail and matching recipient against a list of known-good, non local, addresses

Tags: postfix, sendmail

the feature I am after is similar to the postfix's relay_recipients, but I need to do it in sendmail. I have a list of known good recipient addresses on a server for which this machine acts as the net-facing frontend (mail comes in from the outside, it is pre-processed on the outer box and eventually  relayed to the inner box . the corporate mail server) I cannot do call-forward or LDAP queries tho'.

It is probably a feature of one of of sendmail's *.db files, but my memory or understanding - or both - are currently failing me.

Note: This is a mailwatch/mailscanner box, so mail is queued locally, filtered, then delivered.

Comment: The only way I see is writing a custom milter, or finding one that already does it.

Comment: You could use milter-regexp, but you'll have to present the *good* recipients as a set of patterns. I wouldn't call this a perfect solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [FEAUTURE(virtusertable)](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/features.html#virtusertable) to get equivalent of postfix [relay_recipients_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#relay_recipient_maps)

sendmail.mc

```
LOCAL_CONFIG
dnl virtusertable works by default only for local email domains
dnl $={VirtHost} lists non local domains served by virtusertable
C{VirtHost}example.net
divert(0)
dnl  _VIRTUSER_STOP_ONE_LEVEL_RECURSION_ is described in m4/proto.m4 file
define(`_VIRTUSER_STOP_ONE_LEVEL_RECURSION_')dnl
FEATURE(`virtusertable')
```

virtusertable file (requires makemap compilation):

```
# list of valid emails in example.net
johh.doe@example.net %0
jane.doe@example.net %0
# default entry for example.net
@example.net  ERROR:5.1.1:550 User unknown
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.mail.sendmail/owHMoZIAkDg
news:comp.mail.sendmail thread from 2006.

BTW you can use FEATURE(ldap_routing) with standard sendmail maps (hash,btree,..) instead of LDAP lookups.

Comment: Sounds cool, I'll try that. (I was experimenting with access.db, along the lines of:

   To:user@dom.ain OK
   To:dom.ain             DENY

which also appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually resorted to using access ( FEATURE(`access_db',`hash -T -o /etc/mail/access.db') ) thusly:

```
To:u1@dom.ain   RELAY
To:u2@dom.ain   RELAY
....
robintur.it     DENY
```

The behaviour is as required.